# Mantain columns order while writing flat dataframe into json in databricks using pyspark

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

Hi have to write a flat DF to a json file using pyspark on Databricks. 
The dataframe has the columns in this order:

```
 identifier|plant|  customer|    product|quantity|  deadline|priority
```

I used the following function:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format('json').save('path')
```

But the json file I get has columns in alphabetical order.

Does anyone know how to keep the original sequence of columns?

Comment: I also used     df.coalesce(1).write.format('json').option("inferSchema", myschema).save('path') but it still does not work

Comment: What ```spark``` version are you using? I made a replica of your ```dataframe``` and the columns are in the order of the ```dataframe``` ... not getting alphabetical order

Comment: It should be the 2.4.0